# How to stack multiple columns into one

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

I have this type of dataframe

| team1 | team2. | team3 | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bitdefender | holding | bv | 1 |
| gardner | manufacturing | co | 2 |
| indiana | area | school | 3 |
| nhbb | None | None | 2 |
| phenix | None | None | 2 |

And I Want to create something like this

| teamtogether | number |
| --- | --- |
| bitdefender | 1 |
| holding | 1 |
| bv | 1 |
| gardner | 2 |
| manufacturing | 2 |
| co | 2 |
| indiana | 3 |
| area | 3 |
| school | 3 |

Order does not matter, but the main idea is to stack all columns into one, while keeping also column number duplicated for each one

Answer (score 0):

melt does what you need

```
df.melt(id_vars='number',value_name='teamtogether').drop(columns=['variable'])
```